# Jade to HTML conversion with PHP + Net beans IDE

Tags: javascript, netbeans, pug, netbeans-plugins

I want to convert jade to html.How it can be done via command line

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Node with npm tool
http://learnwebtutorials.com/how-to-convert-jade-to-html  {Guide to convert jade to html}
Refered above